# base does not contain a CLISP linking set error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, clisp

I am trying to call Lisp code from a C function and, while following [the tutorial](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html#ex-call-in), I am stuck at

`clisp-link add base base+sort sort`

This gives me error: `base does not contain a CLISP linking set`.

I have followed the tutorial step-by-step but this point is a blocker. 
Is someone aware of the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are there is no `base` sub-directory in your working directory because you did not build clisp yourself.
Try `clisp -help` to find out where your base is located and give `clisp-link` the full path.

If you supply the full path to your clisp installation directory:

```
clisp-link add /usr/lib/clisp-2.49/base base+sort sort
```

it should work.

The error message you are getting indicates that `base` is missing one or more of the following files:

- `lisp.a`
- `lisp.run`
- `lispinit.mem`
- `modules.h`
- `modules.o`
- `makevars`

in which case you should file a bug report with your vendor.

Comment: I have already tried with full path for base but didn't help.

Comment: did you file the bug report?

Comment: No, I didn't file any bug report because I think it is something from user side, there are many softwares that are using ffi since long, probably we are missing that knowledge on this forum :(